# custom constructors for built-in types in c++

Tags: c++, constructor, built-in-types

Suppose I have defined a class called `Entity` which has a data member which is a pointer to int. So for example

```
class Entity {
public:
    int* ptr;
    // other stuff
};
```

Is there a way to give the type `int*` a constructor which takes an `Entity` object? If I have an Entity object called `my_entity`, I'd like to be able to do something like this

```
int* p(my_entity);
```

or this

```
int* p = my_entity;
```

which would require the compiler implicitly call a constructor for `int*` that takes an `Entity`.

Is this possible? (I know I could define a public `get_pointer()` method in the Entity class and do something like `int* p = my_entity.get_pointer();` but this seems clunky.)

Comment: You could create a [*user-defined conversion*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/cast_operator) for your class. Note that it's often not recommended since it could make code hard to read, understand and maintain. Using explicit "getter" functions are often recommended.

Comment: Cool. Thank you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, there is no constructor for a basic pointer - in the sense that there is no function implicitly called in order to initialise the pointer.

The closest you can come is to use a user-defined conversion operator function

```
class Entity
{
     public:

          operator int *();
};

Entity::operator int *()
{
     // return something appropriate that is of type int *
}


//   sample usage in a function somewhere

int *p = some_entity;    // implicitly conversion that calls the operator int *()

int *another_p = static_cast<int *>(some_entity);    //  explicit conversion

int *yet_another_p = some_entity.operator int *();
```

There are variants of this, depending on what form of `const` qualification is needed (e.g.    if the operator function doesn't change the object it acts on, it should be `const` and may be defined as `operator const int *()`).

It is necessary to ensure that the pointer returned by the operator function is treated appropriately.  If the user defined operator function returns a member of `some_entity`, it cannot be used once `some_entity` ceases to exist.    Similarly, if it uses dynamic memory allocation (e.g. return the result of a `new` expression) the caller must explicitly release that memory to avoid a memory leak.

Answer (score 0):

You cant make a constructor for primitive types. Also there is no need to do this using constructor, you could just use a getter as you already mentioned, or a function to which you pass an `Entity` and `int` and store the `int` to `Entity`.

Also you can use a [user-defined conversion](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/cast_operator) as @Some programmer dude said and do something like:

```
int *p = (int*)my_entity;
```

Comment: Thank you :) I'll probably stick to my initial getter function strategy.